# How to filter SelectList with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I tried to filter the SelectList with where clause but i get the following error.

> Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.

```
public SelectList ReadDocumentHeaderTypeList()
{
    using (context = new Pinc_DBEntities())
    {
        List<SelectListItem> seList =
            (from tb in context.tblDocumentHeaderTypes
            select new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)tb.DocumentHeaderTypeID).Trim(),
                Text = tb.DocumentHeaderTypeDescription,
            }).OrderBy(o => o.Text).ToList();
        SelectList slist = new SelectList(seList, "Value", "Text");
        return slist;
    }
}

SelectList sl = (SelectList)rep.ReadDocumentHeaderTypeList().Where(o => o.Value == "5" && o.Value == "6");//Error occurs here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `SelectList` appears to contain a list of `SelectListItem` objects. I'm not sure what it looks like internally, but you had to supply the list of items to the new instance of `SelectList`. I assume you'll have to do that again.

```
... = new SelectList(rep.ReadDocumentHeaderTypeList()
                        .Where(o => o.Value == "5" || o.Value == "6").ToList(),
                     "Value", "Text");
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
SelectList sl = (SelectList)rep.ReadDocumentHeaderTypeList().Where(o => o.Value == "5" && o.Value == "6");
```

to this:

```
SelectList sl = new SelectList(rep.ReadDocumentHeaderTypeList().Where(o => o.Value == "5" && o.Value == "6"));
```

The issue is exactly what the compiler is telling you, that the result of the `Where` is not a `SelectList`. The solution is to make one from the result.

Also, note that your where clause checks that `Value` is equal to `5` *and* equal to `6` which will always be false (assuming `Value` is `string`)

Documentation on the [SelectList constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: hi! my bad it has to be an OR clause.in your answer still had to specify the "Text" and "Value" fields as in Grant Winney's answer.otherwise text is shown as "System.Web.MVC.SelectListItem". so i'm gonna accept Grant's post as the answer and i have up-voted your answer. thanks!